# How to modify knitr output chunk

Tags: r, knitr

I know that it's possible to tweak the output of a `knitr` code chunk so that it
looks the way you want. My problem occurs when using the `parskip` package.
The `parskip` package adds an extra bit of space below the code output, which doesn't
look great. Here's a minimal `.Rnw` file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
Some text above chunk
<<echo=TRUE>>=
2 + 2
@
Some text below. The space above this is too big when using the \texttt{parskip} package.
Some text below. The space above this is too big when using the \texttt{parskip} package.
Some text below. The space above this is too big when using the \texttt{parskip} package.

A nice space between paragraphs.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a Debian with TeX Live 2014 I am unable to see in your example the extra space between the R box and "Some text..." when using `parskip` (at the same time that I see the extra space above "A nice space...", so there are not doubt that I was using the package).

Answer (score 2):

This not an elegant answer but you can 'fix' the excess space with the inclusion of negative vertical space.  See the modified code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
Some text above chunk
<<echo=TRUE>>=
2 + 2
@
\vspace{-1em}  %%% this moves the following text up the height of an 'm'
Some text below. The space above this is too big when using the \texttt{parskip} package.
Some text below. The space above this is too big when using the \texttt{parskip} package.
Some text below. The space above this is too big when using the \texttt{parskip} package.

A nice space between paragraphs.
\end{document}
```